# "Unable To Connect to web server IIS Express" message running project using 3G

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

My project is checked into TFS Online private repo not local repo.

I can debug and run my application when I am connected to my company network.

However if I want to debug and run from my own internet 3G USB dongle as soon as  I click Run (F5)

> I get Unable To Connect to web server 'IIS Express.'

Running a local site with all the files stored on my laptop should have nothing to do with internet.

I restart my computer and it doesn't help. I unchecked the folder to readonly it also doesn't help.

I tried other solutions mentioned of deleting applicationhost.config in my .vs folder it also doesn't help.

I use music sites an youtube to listen while I am working. The company network blocks those sites so I use my 3G stick but this means my dev workflow is each time I have to want to run my application from Visual Studio I have to connect the company network LAN cable. This makes no sense.